# How do depoy a Django Project on a Webgo server

Tags: django, webserver, mod-wsgi

im new to Django i did made a tutorial from w3school, now im at the point to deploy the project but i dont want to deploy the project on my own webhost at Webgo. On the Server there is python and modWSGI. But all tutorial i had read they there realy complicated to deploy a project. Can somebody help me to deploy my project on that webserver its running with apache.
I tried to upload the Project but that was not enought im not sure what to do. The docs are a bit to complicated for me. Thats why i hope sombody can descripe me the approach so a newbie can understand that.

I uploaded my project but its not working

Comment: WSGIScriptAlias /www/light-natural.de/myworld/my_project/my_project/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonHome /www/light-natural.de/myworld/pyvenv
WSGIPythonPath /www/light-natural.de

<Directory /www/light-natural.de/myworld/>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>